# Unable to capture Access token from Azure using this.adalService.acquireToken

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am using ng2-adal for Azure AD authentication. I have created 2 projects, one is Angular 2 and WebAPI. Using ng2-adal, I am able authenticate user and got the Web App access token, but to get access token of Web API, I am using below code

```
public getToken(): any {
        debugger;
        return this.adalService.acquireToken("d3ff1be3-8484-4b28-8b67-7df715a5af79").subscribe(
            token => {
                console.log(token.toString());
            },
            error =>
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
```

Using this code I am getting access code, when i see in developer tools. please find the attachment, but I am not getting in token variable, not going into subscribe callback function. please let me know is there anothe way to get access token of Web API using ng2-adal.

[image]

Thanks,
Raj4MS

Comment: have you news, solution ? I Have the same problem. @Raj4MS